# AS3 - Find first link in text

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, text, find

I need to find the first link in a text with AS3.

This is an example text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur http://www.firstlink.com
adipiscing elit. Maecenas euismod elementum nulla id facilisis.
Suspendisse mattis ullamcorper http://www.secondlink.com neque non pellentesque.
```

The link could look like this:

```
https://www.example.com
https://example.com
http://www.example.com
http://example.com
www.example.com
example.com
```

How can this be done?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for that:

```
var find:RegExp = / (https?\:\/\/[^ ]*)/g;
trace(myText.match(find));
```

The regular expression will look for

1. a whitespace
2. http
3. s but not necessarly
4. ://
5. a bunch of characters that are not whitespaces

The `( )` are there to delimit which group of characters the `RegExp` should catch.
The `g` parameters at the end tells the `RegExp` not to stop looking after the first match.

**ADDENDUM**

If you want to match an URL without http, this should work to get a word with at least one point inside:

```
/ ([a-z\:\/]+\.[a-z\.]+) /g
```

1. At least one character of lowercase alphabet, : and /
2. A dot
3. At least one character of lowercase alphabet and .

Comment: Thanks! How to extend the RegExp to also find links without the _http_? e.g.: `www.example.com`

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I added numbers and uppercase letters recognizing to it, in case anybody needs this: `/([a-zA-Z0-9\:\/]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)/g`